# How to open form 2nd time when it's closed

Tags: c#, .net

i doing window app using c#.net.
i have a form name form_1 with menu-strip.
from the menu-strip of form_1, i am opening same form form_1 and closing the same form_1 after using it but if i click that for the second time it is not showing,if i click that for third time it is showing.
edit:

**mainform**

```
form fm;
bool frm= false;
private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (frm== false)
    {
        fm= new form();
        fm.MdiParent = this;
        fm.Show();
        frm= true;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (fm.IsDisposed)
        {
            frm= false;
        }
    }
}
```

**form**

```
form fm = new form();
fm.MdiParent = this;
fm.Show();
this.Close();
```

Comment: If you close the parent of a form you expect the form to stay visible?

Comment: 1) first click -->  frm = false , it opens and sets frm = true
2) second click --> frm == true ,it does not enter the IF and continues 
   to the else where if is set to false . 
3) third click  --> enters the if statement again because frm == false.

Any one care to venture on the scenarios of 4 and 5 ?

Comment: thank you so much for helping and guiding me Peter Ritchie and eran otzap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect your function `addToolStripMenuItem_Click` to always open `fm` (assuming it is disposed), then you'll need `fm.show()` in the else condition as well. You could try something like this instead...

```
    private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!frm || fm.IsDisposed)
        {
            if (fm != null && fm.IsDisposed) { frm = false; }

            fm = new form();
            fm.MdiParent = this;
            fm.Show();
            frm = true;
        }
    }
```

This probably makes your bool `frm` obsolete, but I left it in in case you're using it for something else.